# How to get pieces for my board game?

Tags: custom-game-pieces

I am creating a board game which requires 2 colors with 5 pieces each. As of right now, I use pennies and dimes. What is an easy way to get pieces for my board game?

Comment: Are you talking about a large print run, or just a couple of copies.

Comment: Colored glass beads from a craft shop with a floral dept (e.g. Michael's)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Gamecrafter](https://www.thegamecrafter.com/) allows you to buy all sorts of pieces for your game.  If you use their pieces, you can even upload your game and have people buy it on demand.

Answer (score 5):

[MeepleSource](https://www.meeplesource.com/index.php) has all kinds of game accessories, including custom meeples. I would definitely check them out.

Comment: Broken link :( You can find it on [the Wayback Machine archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315001557/http://www.meeplesource.com/custom.php), but not sure that's much use unless they're still trading!

Comment: Thanks! That link was working just a few days ago, looks like they've updated their site as well. Either way, I've updated the link!

Answer (score 5):

If you want *custom* game pieces, you could have them 3D printed at [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/) -- they do great work.  As folks have already mentioned, game stores (I'll throw in a link to [TheWarStore](http://www.thewarstore.com/chessex-glass-marker-gaming-stones.html)) often have markers and tokens of all sorts.  One last option is poker chips, which are often available from the dollar store or even in grocery/convenience stores.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy huge lots of various game pieces on e-bay.